# Handling undefined condition in ngClass Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to assign a class based on two objects.

```
<div class="col" [ngClass]="{'d-none':item.FinancialDetails?.length===0 || item.FinancialDetails===undefined || itemFinancials===false }">
    <app-financials [financials]="item.FinancialDetails"></app-financials>
</div>
```

Here As you can see for the same object FinancialDetails I am now checking two conditions because length alone not working as expected.

But is there is any way to combine those first two conditions together. I mean the length and undefined condition.

Comment: Perhaps, you mean this? `[ngClass]="{'d-none': !(item.FinancialDetails && item.FinancialDetails.length > 0) || itemFinancials===false }"`

Comment: Sorry but again there are two conditions for the same object FinancialDetails, isnt it? I was thinking is there is any way to make it one condition. Like checking undefined and no value in array.

Comment: Or even shortcut like this: `[ngClass]="{'d-none': !(item.FinancialDetails?.length > 0) || itemFinancials===false }"`. With `?.`, it prevent failure when accessing `length` due to `item.FinancialDetails` was `null` or `undefined`. Negate it to check that when empty array, `null` or `undefined`, it returns `true`.

Comment: Object is possibly 'undefined' when trying that way

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of Safe Operator (`?`).
Try below code:

```
<div class="col" [ngClass]="{'d-none': item?.FinancialDetails?.length === 0  || itemFinancials===false }">
    <app-financials [financials]="item.FinancialDetails"></app-financials>
</div>
```

Only change having single condition - `item?.FinancialDetails?.length === 0`